# Android file is hidden on external storage

Tags: java, android, file-io

I am writing out a file to the external storage on android. The file shows up in my device when I browse to location using the ap ES file explorer.

But when I plug my device in to windows, the file does not show up.

Furthermore if I write an empty file named "test.wav" to Ringtones folder, no test.wav will show up in my ringtones settings.

But, if I create an empty file in windows named "test.wav", and drag and drop into my Ringtones folder, it will then properly show up in my ringtones browser in settings.

Code I am using is a follows.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
             Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES), "testfile.wav");
    file.setReadable(true);

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        stream = new DataOutputStream(fileOut);
        stream.flush();
                    stream.close();
            //this code successfully creates a file
                    // but file is not viewable by all means

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You need to invoke the media scanner.  This question has many duplicates here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android uses tables to keep track of images, videos, sounds and so on these tables called " **content providers** " for example it uses **MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA** for images Note that these tables are used for the view this illustrates why you can only see it using ES. When you add new file manually, you need to add an entry for this file in the corresponding table or refresh your music library in case of sound file was added, but when you add file using windows the device's driver updates its tables automatically. Try refreshing your music application or even restarting your phone if this solves the problem updating your content provider is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I think that it is `/extsd` showing when you plug your device into Windows, whereas external storage is actually `/sdcard`. so your file is in `/sdcard`, not in `/extsd`, that's why you don't see it. At least whenever I plugged Android tab into Windows, I could only browse its removable SD, i.e. `/extsd` but I couldn't see `/sdcard`